# Store Variable Data In Array

Tags: php

I am facing a problem while storing variable data in array and then array to session. Only for one time the value is stored in array at 0 index, but when the next page loads on next button click to load the next test the value of array is overwritten.

```
<?php session_start();
$cat_name = $_POST["cat_name"];
$which_test_id = $_POST["which_test_id"];
echo $correct = $_POST["correct"];
$answers[] = array('correct' => $correct);
$_SESSION["results"] = $answers;
print_r($_SESSION["results"]); ?>
```

Comment: Append to array with `[]` notation

Comment: @SaurabhSinha He has.

Answer (score 2):

Just get answers before set :)

```
<?php session_start();
$cat_name = $_POST["cat_name"];
$which_test_id = $_POST["which_test_id"];
echo $correct = $_POST["correct"];
$answers = (array_key_exists("results", $_SESSION)) ? $_SESSION["results"] : array();
$answers[] = array('correct' => $correct);
$_SESSION["results"] = $answers;
print_r($_SESSION["results"]);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is submitted then value shows

```
<?php session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$cat_name = $_POST["cat_name"];
$which_test_id = $_POST["which_test_id"];
echo $correct = $_POST["correct"];
$answers[] = array('correct' => $correct);
$_SESSION["results"] = $answers;
}
print_r($_SESSION["results"]); ?>
```

Comment: did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

1.You don't need the "[ ]" while declaring an array.

2.The data gets overridden because you didn't check whether the data was set in the first place.

```
<?php 
ini_set('session.cookie_domain',"localhost");
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $cat_name = $_POST["cat_name"];
    $which_test_id = $_POST["which_test_id"];
    echo $correct = $_POST["correct"];
    $answers = array('correct' => $correct);
    if(!isset($_SESSION["results"]))
    {
        $_SESSION["results"] = $answers;
    }
}
print_r($_SESSION["results"]); ?>
```